# Fatal signal 11 after enabling proguard

Tags: android, imagemagick, apk, proguard, fatal-error

When I create my app and lauch it from my IDE (**Eclipse**) app is working great, but when I build APK, it's crashing, but I can't figure out why? 
It shows **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1)**. I uses  https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick library in my app.

Thanks in Advance..

---

```
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:4.0.4/IMM76L/eng.build.20130311.122614:eng/release-keys'
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010): pid: 7996, tid: 8064  >>> com.sample.myapp <<<
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010): pid: 7996, tid: 8064, pkg name: com.sample.myapp
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010):  eax 0b37f318  ebx 0000000c  ecx 00000000  edx 08536ce0
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010):  esi 08536ce0  edi 0b37f318
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010):  xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000 xss 0000007b
06-15 13:39:21.830: I/DEBUG(8010):  eip 08536ce6  ebp 0b37f318  esp b4b61a80  flags 00010206
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  eip: 08536ce6  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  eip: 000001d7  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  eip: 00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010): stack: 
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a80  00000002  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a84  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a88  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a8c  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a90  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a94  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a98  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61a9c  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61aa0  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61aa4  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61aa8  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61aac  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61ab0  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61ab4  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61ab8  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #00  b4b61abc  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     ......  ......  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f31c  000001d7  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f320  0b37d4a8  [heap]
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f324  319f96a8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f328  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f32c  1d700001  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f330  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f334  3ba1fe84  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f338  109ffc40  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f33c  3ba1fe7c  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f340  31a165e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f344  109ffc54  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f348  3120282c  /system/lib/libdvm.so-arm
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f34c  109ffbe8  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f350  311a4438  /system/lib/libdvm.so-arm (_Z20dvmDecodeIndirectRefP6ThreadP8_jobject)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f354  311a68ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so-arm
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #01  0b37f358  00000010  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     ......  ......  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96ac  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96b0  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96b4  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96b8  00000018  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96bc  00000023  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96c0  313b90b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96c4  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96c8  319f96e0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96cc  0e3baed4  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96d0  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96d4  00000029  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96d8  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96dc  0000006b  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96e0  313b9928  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96e4  00000000  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     #02  319f96e8  00000029  
06-15 13:39:22.420: I/DEBUG(8010):     ......  ......
```

**This is my code**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                              try{
                                ImageInfo info=new ImageInfo(selectedImagePath);
                                MagickImage imageCMYK = new MagickImage(info);


                            if(imageCMYK.getColorspace()==12){
                                  bitmap=getCMYKImageFromPath(selectedImagePath);

                            }
                            else {
                                  //do something

                                }
                            }
                            }catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;




                        }
```

This is the code which retrieves the image

```
  public Bitmap getCMYKImageFromPath(String path) {

                            try {
                                ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(path); // where the CMYK image is
                                MagickImage imageCMYK = new MagickImage(info);

                                Log.d("DEBUG", "ColorSpace BEFORE => " + imageCMYK.getColorspace());
                                boolean status = imageCMYK.transformRgbImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace);
                                Log.d("DEBUG", "ColorSpace AFTER => " + imageCMYK.getColorspace() + ", success = " + status);

                                bitmap = MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(imageCMYK);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return bitmap;
                        }
```

Comment: Did you got solution for this case?

Comment: @Abirami No, i did not get any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the native library is using reflection to call back into the Java code, you need to preserve the called classes, fields, and methods. Otherwise, ProGuard may rename or even remove them, leading to a confusing crash in the native code. Without knowing the internals of the library, you could preserve all of its classes, fields, and methods:

```
-keep class magick.** { *; }
-keep class fakeawt.** { *; }
```

If this helps, you could try narrowing these options down to keep the minimal number of classes, fields, and methods.